# Retrieving the previous 3 posts with the same product ID

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

The platform I'm trying to build has a little sidebar which should display the previous posts that are have the same product ID. So that the user can easily navigate to more resources categorized under the same ID.

Here's the where clause that I tried out, but unfortunately it is only retrieving the top 3 posts with the same ID and not the previous posts.

```
@prev = Post.where("product_id = ? AND created_at >= ?", params[:product_id], params[:created_at]).order('created_at desc').limit(3)
```

Am I missing something out here?

EDIT: Sample Output

If the table contains Post A, B, C, D and E. Then for Post A, it should display B, C, and D. And for Post B, it should display C, D and E.

So, I want to fetch the previous 3 posts for each post. And not just the top 3 posts.

Comment: You are ordering your result of where clause by created_at desc and limiting it by 3. So it will pick up the latest 3 records. You want to show all the records then dont limit it.

Comment: I actually want to show only the previous 3 posts! Hence the limit.

Answer (score 0):

To select the top three posts just remove the created_at parameter like this:

```
@prev = Post.where("product_id = ?", params[:product_id]).order('created_at desc').limit(3)
```

Comment: Oh no. I don't want it to fetch the top 3 posts. I want it to fetch the previous 3 posts. So for Post A, it should fetch the previous 3 posts before Post A was created.

Comment: Like if the table has Post A,B,C,D and E. Then for Post A, it should display B,C, and D. And for Post B, it should display C, D and E.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

First finding the product

```
@product = Post.find_by_id(params[:product_id])
```

And then based on product's created_at date finding all the products which were created after that:-

```
@prev = Post.where("created_at > ? AND project_id = ?", @product.created_at, @product.id).order('created_at desc').limit(3)
```

Comment: This would fetch me posts of different product_id's. I need the previous posts to be of the same product_id also.